# How to write from a Raspberry Pi camera to a WebSocket?

Tags: python, opencv, websocket, uv4l

I am working on a web app using Django on the server side and I'd like to stream from the camera to the browser. I already tried methods like HLS with the ffmpeg segment muxer, but with such methods I don't have the full control over the stream. So I thought about sending the video manually over a websocket and then playing it with Media Source Extensions.

On the server side I use UV4L and OpenCV to capture the video, but I found no good way of writing a segment over a websocket, because OpenCV only writes the data to a file. The only possible [solution](http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.de/2012/02/encode-and-decode-video-from-memory.html) I found involves some changes to OpenCV itself.

Does anyone know an alternative or how to do this?

Comment: You could try to read the file's output inside a loop and stream each chunk every n milliseconds.

Comment: I forgot to explain why that is a problem. I only use a flash storage for the Pi and I don't want to destroy it by constant write operations.

Comment: Have you tried with tmpfs ? https://www.howtoforge.com/storing-files-directories-in-memory-with-tmpfs in memory directories, you won't use your flash storage. You will also have to delete each chunk from the file or you could exhaust your allocated memory .

Comment: It kind of depends what the other end is expecting. Do you have a specification of what formats/containers/codecs Media Source Extensions can handle?

Comment: MSE doesn't add any new supported formats, so I am pretty much limited to MP4 H.264. It just makes it possible to put a video together out of multiple segments.

tmpfs is a possible solution, but I think that there should be a better one. I also found out that OpenCV works with GStreamer, but then I need to split the video with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimalistic example that uses in-memory Redis key-value store. The Redis database is an intermediary between continuous camera capture process and a Tornado web server:

https://github.com/vmlaker/hello-websocket